# Error: Have two Action bar in activity_main.xml (Android Studio)

Tags: android, appbar

Error:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJrJ5.png
```

[image]

Code here: `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RxpvdE`
(Sorry I cant't post code here because of when post error 4 space Ctr+K..???)

Comment: Just use NoActionBar theme .

Answer (score 0):

Just change theme `MainActivity` in `Mainifest` file .

From

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

To

```
"android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Like this Way,

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:label="zzzzzzzzzz"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Manifest file**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="zzzzzzzzzz"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]